# Unix Time not displaying correctly | NEXTCORD

Tags: python, nextcord

I have a bot with a giveaway command.

## Info

API: Discord API via Nextcord

Language: Python

The module that interprets time (from human time [1m | 1h | 1d] to seconds): humanfriendly

## Expectations

I wanted a sort of... uh... a "ends in" thing. Discord has a built-in Unix Time thingy that's syntax is this:

> <t:UNIX:type>

Unix is the UNIX time, type is the- well... type. E.g., R as relative time

## Result

Well, I met this when I used 1m (1 minute):

> Ends in [some whole 2 months!]

Yes, it appeared as two months there. The actual time was working correctly. The giveaway **can** end in one minute. But my problem is with the time display.

## Code

```py
@commands.command(name="gstart")
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_guild=True)
    async def gquickStart(self, ctx, gtime, *, gprize: str):
        if gtime == None:
            return await ctx.send("Include a time.")
        elif gprize == None:
            return await ctx.send("How are we gonna giveaway nothing?")
        gawtime = humanfriendly.parse_timespan(gtime)
        gawtimetuple = nextcord.utils.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(gawtime)
        gwembed = nextcord.Embed(
            title=f"**:tada: {gprize} :tada:**",
            description=f"Ends in <t:{int(time.mktime(gawtimetuple.timetuple()))}:R> <t:{int(time.mktime(gawtimetuple.timetuple()))}:T> \n {ctx.author.mention} is giving away **{gprize}**!",
            color=nextcord.Colour.green())
        gwemend = nextcord.Embed(
        title=f"**:tada: GIVEAWAY ENDED :tada:**",
        description = f"{ctx.author.mention} has gave away **{gprize}**!",
            color=nextcord.Colour.red()
        )
        gwembed.set_footer(text=f"Giveaway ends in {gtime}")
        gaw_msg = await ctx.send(embed=gwembed)
        await ctx.message.delete()

        await gaw_msg.add_reaction('')

        await asyncio.sleep(gawtime)

        global new_gaw_msg
        new_gaw_msg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(gaw_msg.id)

        global users
        users = await new_gaw_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
        users.pop(users.index(client.user))

        try:
            winner = random.choice(users)
    
            await ctx.send(f"{winner.mention} has won the giveaway for **{gprize}**")
            await new_gaw_msg.edit(embed=gwemend)
        except IndexError:
            await new_gaw_msg.reply("1 Winner needed for the giveaway, 0 provided")
            await new_gaw_msg.edit(embed=gwemend)
```

---

BTW, if it matters, I use the command in a category.

Please answer if you can.

Thanks in advance,

Beedful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

When constructing the timedelta, the first positional argument is `days`. So, by adding `timedelta(60)` to `utcnow`, you add 60 days to the current time.

An easier method would be simply to convert `utcnow` to a float with `.timestamp()`, then sum that with `gawtime`.

### Code

```py
@commands.command(name="gstart")
@commands.has_permissions(manage_guild=True)
async def gquickStart(self, ctx, gtime, *, gprize: str):
    if gtime is None:
        return await ctx.send("Include a time.")
    elif gprize is None:
        return await ctx.send("How are we gonna giveaway nothing?")
    gawtime = humanfriendly.parse_timespan(gtime) 
    end_time = nextcord.utils.utcnow().timestamp() + gawtime
    gwembed = nextcord.Embed(
        title=f"**:tada: {gprize} :tada:**",
        description=f"Ends in <t:{int(end_time)}:R> <t:{int(end_time)}:T> \n {ctx.author.mention} is giving away **{gprize}**!",
        color=nextcord.Colour.green()
    )
```

Unrelated: From [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)

> Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with is or is not, never the equality operators.

### Reference

[`parse_timestamp`](https://humanfriendly.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#humanfriendly.parse_timespan)

[`utcnow`](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#nextcord.utils.utcnow)

[`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @TheFungusAmongUs. I would like to ask a question. The `gawtime` variable defines the time that I will use the `asyncio.sleep()` function. Will your code effect the time? Or will it proceed normally and end the giveaway in the specified time?

Comment: Ah, that's true. I've edited the post to reflect this.